# XML HttpRequest Object

Tags: xml, html

This [W3school HTML table example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp) reads a file named "cd_catalog.xml".

```
<script>
xmlhttp.open("GET","cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
...
</script>
```

The "Try it yourself" example works as advertised.

However, when I change the file name to its URL,

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml
```

it does not work.

For example:

```
<script>
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
...
</script>
```

What is the correct way to `GET` a URL for an XML file that achieves the same results as `GET` XML file stored locally on a server, such as "cd_catalog.xml"?

Comment: Make sure you're using the same protocol for the request.

Comment: I mean I don't know wether you're using http or https.

Comment: I mean the protocol you use to go on TryIt, the one that it says in the broswer's address bar.

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: This error came out: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ontomatica.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: OK, TY for this. I'll check with our Server Admin about correcting the request.